# Keycloak AD/kerberos Integration

Tags: keycloak, kerberos

If I integrate an AD in keycloak (like LDAP) I Import the users in my keycloak DB.

after integrating that user federated provider if in the AD user provider I enable the kerberos integration, the users coming from kerberos (related to that AD) are merged with the user that are considered from the AD?

I have to understand this: if I create a userd federation with an AD and inside the user federation I enable the kerberos integration, when a user log in with kerberos, keycloak consider that user like a “user federation user” imported during the creation of the AD user federation, or it creates a new user related to kerberos principal?

thanks